# is it possible to secure android apk to specific tablet

Tags: android, apk, extract

I have developed an android application and I want to distribute the application on tablet. This means my client will not require to download the apk as it comes with tablet.

This software is for training purpose i.e. video and other documents.

I don't want the apk to be extracted, in another words, I would like to bound the apk to run a specific device.

In summary, my aim is to deliver the apk with tablet device (and I want to avoid extraction of the apk).

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user gains root access on the tablet, you cannot do anything to avoid this.

However without root access, if the apk comes shipped with the tablet, there is no way that someone can send it to other tablet/phones.

If you want to add further security, you can do a simple offline authentication, when the app starts.

eg
1) on first install, prompt user(who will be you, since you have to install the app before giving the tablet to an employee - right? if I understood correctly your problem) to give a user and a pass.

2) Then save credentials in phone(using preferences), and later on(step 3) match them with some hardcoded ones in your apps code.

3) Each time app starts, do a quick check of preferences credentials, and if it doesn't match, close the application.

While this isn't very good way of securing your app, you may come up with a more reliable solution. If tablets have internet access all the time, you can add a proper username/password authentication, but you have to create some sort of accounts to all of your users.

Comment: thanks Paschalis,what protection exist to avoid rooting(anti-rooting)

Comment: It can rely to the hardware vendor to make it hard to achieve root. eg if the bootloader is locked, achieving root might be more difficult. But I think hackers at XDA developers always can find a root exploit! You are welcome! Also if I knew more info about your problem, I might give a better answer!

Answer (score 0):

Did you know something about `Signed-apk`?? First of all create your account on `play-store` and get the `keystore` for your project. then create a `signed-apk` using `keystore` and `password` given.